# What is the hex number after function offset (after "/") in crash dump?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, crash-dumps

In the crash dump, the RIP points to function_name(0xoffset/0xab). I understood offset and its use while analysing. Can some one tell me what is the 0xab denotes here?. How is it useful in analyzing the dump?

Comment: Hi, should it be possible for you to add some sample to the question?  Where did you get that? you mean a kernel crash dump, an application crash dump, a core file, what?

Comment: Hi, It is a kernel crash dump. Following is kernel crash dump I collected using linux-crashdump utility. "RIP: 0010:vprintk_emit+0x1ef/0x3b0". In this information, vprintk_emit is the function and 0x1ef is the offset from the function. I would like to know what is the hex number "0x3b0" denotes and how that number can be used in the analysis.

Comment: as you don't post actual examples, only supposed ones, the only way you allow me to dig into your problem is to dig into de documentation, or the kernel source code, to see what it is, a thing you can do yourself.  Cannot help.  Sorry.  I was guessing the first number is the actual offset inside the function, and the second the address of the end of the function (or the function size, in bytes) but without actual samples of code, nothing more can be said.